# If angle brackets are the only non-encoded special characters in my URL, is this by itself, dangerous?

Tags: c#, javascript, security, xss, webmatrix

Let me make it clear that I am only talking about possible security breaches in a URL (not on the page, in a query, or anywhere else).

The problem is that I have noticed that using "GET" with a form *doesn't* encode the angle brackets.

C#.Net doesn't forgive angle brackets being in a URL when using `Request.QueryString` therefore, I am forced to use `Request.Unvalidated`, but this could create a security risk if angle brackets alone in a URL are a security risk (i.e. the other special characters like parenthesis, apostrophes, quotations, etc. *ARE* encoded properly).

At this site: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet I read that JavaScript can be ran straight from a URL, although I have never made a successful attempt at this, I *NEED* to be sure beforehand if I need to have the submit button (which, of course, won't have that type if I do it this way) point to my own Javascript, encode it myself, and then use JavaScript to appropriately submit the form from there, OR if I should just request the data unvalidated and move on.

Normally I would just take the route that I can guarantee to be the safest, but it seems anti-good practice to force my users to have javascript just to submit a simple search form.

Comment: For what it's worth: try typing `javascript:alert%28%27hello%21%27%29` into your browser's address bar.  If by encoding you mean URL-encoding, that's worthless to protect against script links.

Comment: @cHao Okay, it does nothing at all. I think the browser is automatically omitting it. But yeah, that looks like what I read about. Encoding doesn't help against this? Is this a way to run Javascript in the url?

Comment: @cHao Of course, if I was going to write it as a link to the page, I would just HTML encode it (and URL encode too, although not in that order). I guess I was mistaken thinking that javascript could be ran straight from the url itself. I was just concerned because user data would end up in the url without encoded angle brackets. After I retrieve it validated or not, I know how to properly encode it for the given environment I intend to write it to (Although, in my case I will be using it as a search term for SQL [don't worry, I will be parameterizing the value, of course]).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am only talking about possible security breaches in a URL (not on the page, in a query, or anywhere else)

The URL by itself doesn't cause security breaches. The security issues potentially occur when your page/site takes the user-entered information and displays it on the page (XSS) or puts it in a query (SQL Injection), etc.

RequestValidation is intended to protect you from taking dangerous querystrings and displaying them on your site. For example, if the querystring was `?searchterm=<script>alert('XSS!');</script>` and you had code similar to this:

`SearchTermLabel.Text = "You searched for " + Request["searchterm"];`

The user's search string would be rendered to the page and run as script.

Now, on whether you want to disable RequestValidation.. Can a legitimate search query include the `<` character or anything else that triggers RequestValidation? If so, you'll need to disable RequestValidation or use `Unvalidated` and manually validate/clean the search string. Otherwise, RequestValidation is generally only triggered by someone being mischievous, and personally, as long as they can't cause a security issue, I'm not too worried about their user experience. There are also ways to catch the HttpRequestValidationException and show an attractive error page if you want to take that route.

Comment: Thank you, Sir, that's what I wanted to know. I guess I misunderstood what I read when I thought I read that JavaScript could be run from the URL alone. I am in no way worried about what happens after I request the data, because then I have full control (that is, I can encode however I need) over that data once C# can touch it on the server-side.